# Set theory exericse involving unions and complements

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $X$ be a set. $A\subset X$ and $B\subset X$

> $A\subseteq B$ iff $A^c\cup B = X$

My attempt: Suppose $A\subseteq B$ and $x\in A^c\cup B = X$ then $x\in A^c$ or $x\in B$ or both. If $x\in A^c$ then $x\notin A$ but this is a contradiction.

Not sure where to go from here any suggestions is greatly appreciated

Comment: Draw two  Venn diagrams, one with $A\subset B,$ and one with $ A\not \subset B.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $A\subseteq B,$ then $B^c\subseteq A^c$. Now $X =B\cup B^c\subseteq B\cup A^c\subseteq X.$  We proved: $A^c\cup B = X.$

Let $A^c\cup B = X.$ If $x\in A \subseteq X,$ then $x\in X= A^c\cup B$. Since $x\notin A,$ we have $x\in B.$ We proved: $A\subseteq B.$

Comment: I am sort of skeptical on the fact that if $A\subseteq B$ then $B^c\subseteq A^c$

Comment: Let $A\subseteq B.$  if $x\in B^c,$ $x\notin B.$ so by assumption $x\notin A;$ which means $x\in A^c.$